# Insert value to empty table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to insert value to my empty tables but I can't do this. I used this query but it failed.

```
INSERT INTO phpbb_users(user_avatar) VALUES ('g2_1399642751.png') WHERE user_avatar = NULL;
```

It has  a syntax error.

And tried this:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO phpbb_users(user_avatar) VALUES ('g2_1399642751.png');
```

have this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OR IGNORE INTO phpbb_users(user_avatar) VALUES ('g2_1399642751.png')' at line 1
```

Comment: `INSERT` adds a new column to the DB, so it can't be combined with `WHERE` (unless you are inserting based on a `SELECT` from another table), if you want to modify existing records, use `UPDATE`.

Comment: What did you discover when you followed the advice "*check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version*"?

Answer (score 2):

For your first query,

```
INSERT INTO phpbb_users(user_avatar) VALUES ('g2_1399642751.png') WHERE user_avatar = NULL;
```

The problem is that you can not use `where` clause with insert statement like this. You can either use the insert into... and then select using the where clause.

You may try like this:

```
INSERT INTO phpbb_users(user_avatar) 
VALUES ('g2_1399642751.png')
```

or if you want to select it from the table then try like this:

```
INSERT INTO phpbb_users(user_avatar) 
select 'g2_1399642751.png' from phpbb_users where user_avatar IS NULL;
```

Although this one is not so advantageous as this would add redundant code in your table. And if the table `phpbb_users` is empty then it will add nothing.

And if the value is an existing one then you can try to update the value like this:

```
UPDATE phpbb_users
  SET user_avatar = 'g2_1399642751.png'
WHERE user_avatar IS NULL
```

Comment: What's the advantage of the second insert query? If the table iis empty it will do nothing, also if the table contains several user_avatar entries which are NULL you insert "g2_1399642751.png'" several times...

Comment: @MrTux:- I have just provided the syntax which I think is the main problem with OP. He has not provided the table structure so it is hard to predict. But I do agree with you suggestion. Waiting for OP to comment!

Comment: @MrTux:- Updated my answer with your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE

If the row already exists and you are changing/Updating value of it do as follows:

```
UPDATE phpbb_users
  SET user_avatar = 'g2_1399642751.png'
WHERE user_avatar IS NULL
```

### INSERT

If you are trying to add a new row

```
INSERT INTO phpbb_users(user_avatar) 
VALUES ('g2_1399642751.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that in SQL you cannot check for `NULL` using the equal sign. You have to use `IS` instead (it's a special case). Also for INSERT you cannot use a `WHERE` condition.

```
INSERT INTO phpbb_users(user_avatar) VALUES ('g2_1399642751.png');
```

Your second try with `OR IGNORE` doesn't use the correct syntax. `OR IGNORE` doesn't make SQL to ignore syntax errors, but only errors caused by key/constraint violations.- Correct would be:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO phpbb_users(user_avatar) VALUES ('g2_1399642751.png');
```

Comment: that's not the only problem with the query!